# AWS Cloudformation - use AWS::NoValue within Fn::Sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation and I want to be able to use the pseudo value 
`AWS::NoValue` within the `Fn::Sub` like this:

```
!Sub ["ATL_DATASET_URL=${DatasetURL}", 
       DatasetURL: !If [IsURLProvided, 
                        !Ref BitbucketDatasetURL, 
                        !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]]
```

My Template passes validation but does not deploy. Here is the error message I get when I click Create Stack.

`Template error: every value of the context object of every Fn::Sub object must be a string or a function that returns a string`

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip setting a value for `DatasetURL`, make the `!If` to return an empty string `''` when the condition evaluates to false instead of `AWS::NoValue`.

Returning `AWS::NoValue` when false, removes the mapping for `DatasetURL`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although what would help is if the ATL_DATASET_URL parameter is removed if the value is blank

Comment: I believe @Marcin's answer solves that! If not, can you provide more information as to against which property this !Sub function used.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to @franklinsijo is to swap the `If` and `Sub` statements if you want to actually remove the property (e.g. `YourPropertyName`) if `BitbucketDatasetURL` is not given.

```
  YourPropertyName: !If
      - IsURLProvided 
      - !Sub ["ATL_DATASET_URL=${DatasetURL}", DatasetURL: !Ref BitbucketDatasetURL]
      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Or shorter

```
  YourPropertyName: !If
      - IsURLProvided 
      - !Sub "ATL_DATASET_URL=${BitbucketDatasetURL}"
      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```